# Access tweet annotations via tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I'm using the python library `tweepy` in order to extract data from the `twitter api v2`.
The api also possesses the option to provide `tweet annotations`, which are basically categorization of certain elements used in the tweet. (The endpoint and documentation of this is available at: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/annotations/overview).

My question would be if there is a way to call this endpoint via tweepy? Or is there another way to access the automatic categorization of words using tweepy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tweepy [documentations](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html?highlight=annotations#tweepy.Tweet.context_annotations):

```
 tweepy.Tweet.context_annotations
```

should give you the infos you want.